# Java netty websocket implementation

Tags: java, netty, java-websocket

I am trying to write a simple server which receives an http request, and upgrade it to websocket connection. For some reason I cannot find any implementation where the server is the one sending the message to the client.
The handshake returning ChannelFuture is only completed when the first message is received from the client but that never happens, cause my flow is that the server will send something to the client first.
In golang I can write this in 2 seconds, for some reason I cannot find any java netty websocket implementation that does that.

Any help ?

Regards,
Rani